# gulp-less messes with global variable

Tags: less, gulp, gulp-less

I'm trying to pass a version string from gulp to less, as demonstrated in the following example project:

- package.json:

  ```
  {
    "name": "webui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.9.0",
      "gulp-less": "^3.0.5"
    }
  }
  ```
- gulpfile.js:

  ```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var less = require('gulp-less');

  var LESS_PARAMS = {
    globalVars: {
      webUiVersion: '0.0.0'
    }
  };

  gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('test.less')
      .pipe(less(LESS_PARAMS))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
  })
  ```
- test.less:

  ```
  .test {
    background: url("test.jpg?v=@{webUiVersion}")
  }
  ```

When running `gulp less`, the generated `test.css`file looks like this:

```
.test {
  background: url("test.jpg?v=0 0");
}
```

As you can see, `gulp-less` somehow transformed `0.0.0` into `0 0`. If I use a simple string without dots or `0`, like `123asdf`, the replacement works fine. Also, directly calling

```
lessc --global-var='webUiVersion="0.0.0"' test.less
```

on the command line produces the desired result.

So my questions are:

- Is this intentional behaviour or a bug?
- Is there a way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to fix this issue: The trick is to enclose the string that should be passed to less in quotes, that is writing `webUiVersion: '"0.0.0"'` instead of `webUiVersion: '0.0.0'` in `gulpfile.js`.

The reason for this has been pointed out by [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) below: The value of `webUiVersion` is directly passed to less. Without the quotes, `0.0.0` is parsed as two numbers, namely `0.0` followed by `.0`, which results in `0 0` in the generated CSS.

Comment: This is not a workaround but the proper method in fact. When you pass a *string* via JS stuff you need *two* sets of quotes - one for JS and second for Less. W/o second quotes `webUiVersion: '0.0.0'` results in `@webUiVersion: 0.0.0;` which is interpreted as two numbers (`0.0` followed by `.0` thus resulting in CSS's `0 0` in the end).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! I'll adapt my answer accordingly.